# Ubuntu Terminal Slowing Down Due to Transparency or Font Size

Tags: gnome-terminal

I decided to make the background of my terminal transparent for purely cosmetic reasons. Suddenly my terminal is rendering slower. This may be a stupid question but has anyone else seen this side effect or is this something else going on on my machine? Does terminal re render the background every time?

I am also using NoMachine to access a remote machine but the connection is fast. Also using xfce window manager.

Corollary: Could font size also slow down terminal?

EDIT: I changed the font size back to twelve and now my terminal appears to be back to normal. Why would this happen?

Comment: Can you clarify if the rendering issue is visible only within the remote connection, or everywhere whilst physically on this terminal/box with it enabled?

Comment: @gravity actually the changing the font size back to twelve fixed the problem

Comment: Great!  Glad you fixed it.  Would you post this as an answer to your own question and (48 hours later) accept it for others who may have a similar issue, please?

Comment: @gravity I really want to know why though... New question though or as part of this?